# prove the Limit of the sequence $A_{n}$, when $A_{1} = \sqrt{3}$ and $A_{n+1} = \sqrt{3A_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

is it sufficient to show that since the limit of a sequence $A_{m}$ where $\forall m, \;A_{m}=\sqrt{3}$ is just $\sqrt{3}=3^{\frac{1}{2}}$, the limit of $A_{n}$ will be 3 to some power? I know from looking at the terms of the sequence that $$\lim_{n \to \infty }A_{n}=3^{\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}}$$But im not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: Do you want to determine the limit *knowing* that the sequence converges, or do you want to prove that it converges as well?

Comment: I should probably show it converges as well

Comment: That sequence looks monotonic and is also bounded above. That will show its convergence. The value of the limit can be gotten by assuming its existence and that $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ will go to the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $A_1 = \sqrt{3} < 3$. Assume $A_n < 3 \Rightarrow A_{n+1} = \sqrt{3A_n} < \sqrt{3\cdot 3} = 3$. Thus by induction, $A_n < 3, \forall n \geq 1$. Also, by induction again, $A_{n+1} = \sqrt{3A_n} > \sqrt{3A_{n-1}} = A_n$. Thus $\{A_n\}$ is an increasing sequence. So it converges to some positive number $A$. Hence $A = \sqrt{3A} \Rightarrow A^2= 3A \Rightarrow A(A-3) = 0 \Rightarrow A = 3$ since $A > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $$A_n=3^{B_n}$$

Note that by induction, $$B_{n+1}=\frac{B_n+1}{2}$$

Now, $$B_{n+1}-1=\frac{B_n-1}{2}$$ implying $B_n-1$ is a geometric series where $B_1-1=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{3x}$, note that $f(0) = 0$, $f(3) = 3$, and
for $x \in [0,3]$, we have $x \le f(x) \le 3$.

We have $A_{n+1} = f(A_n)$.

Since $\sqrt{3} \in [0,3]$, we see that $A_n$ is non decreasing and
$\sqrt{3} \le A_n \le 3$. Hence $A_n \uparrow A$ for some $\sqrt{3} \le A \le 3$.

Then $f(A) = A$ by continuity, and hence $A= 3$.